# Are exponential families uniformly continuous?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, asymptotics, point-estimation

It is common to consider log-likelihood $$l(x_1,\cdots,x_n,\theta) :=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \log f\left(x_i,\theta\right)$$

where $f$ is density function of $X$.

Under what conditions is the function $l:\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\to\mathbb{R}$ uniformly continuous? Especially, is $l$ uniformly continuous when $f$ is exponential family density? For example, Gaussian worries me a little bit since its support is not compact.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaximumLikelihood.html

Comment: @Carl Do you mind elaborating how that page answers my question?

Comment: Differentiablilty of Eqs. (11-15).